# Having error in using copy constructor

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I wrote this code - in dev-cpp -about class of time. I used copy-constructor in this program, but I received this error: "[Error] 'Time t2' previously declared here"
What's the reason and What should I do?

```
 #include<iostream>
 using namespace std;
 class Time{
     public:
         int hour;
         int min;
         int sec;
         Time(int h,int m, int s){
             this->hour=h;
             this->min=m;
             this->sec=s;
         }
         Time(Time *t){
             t->hour=this->hour;
             t->sec=this->sec;
         }
 };
 void print(Time *t){
            cout<<t->hour<<':'<<t->min<<':'<<t->sec<<endl;
         }
 int main(){
     Time t1(6,18,25);
     Time t2(11,45,13);
     Time(&t2);
     print(&t1);
     cout<<endl;
     print(&t2);
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: You should: a) find out which line is causing the problem and b) assign members of `this` in the copy constructor based on the parameter (and not the other way around)

Comment: You have a vexing parse. Change that line to `(Time)(&t2)`. That still won't fix your other problems though.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: `Time(Time*)` is not a copy-constructor. `Time(Time const&)` is but the fact is that you don't need an explicitly defined copy-constructor since your compiler will provide one for you.

Comment: copy constructors have a signature of `Foo(const Foo &)`.  `Foo(Foo *)` is just a constructor that takes a `Foo*`.

Comment: This line: Time(&t2)

Comment: I want to learn using copy-constructors!

Comment: @AmirHavangi But I don't understand what you want to do in your main function... What do you want to copy, and where?

Comment: I expected this output for t2: t2.hour=6 & t2.sec=25 & t2.min=45

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your main() function, you need to name your third Time variable.

```
Time(&t2);
```

should be

```
Time t3(&t2);
```

Also, what @leemes said.

Comment: I received correct answer in another way that It wasn't my mean. I don't want to define third object for copying attributes of two objects! What should I do?

Comment: Then don't use a constructor for it. Constructors create new objects, by their nature. Write a function instead, by giving it a name other than `Time` and a return value (possibly `void`), e.g. `void copyTo(Time *t) { ... }`, and call it on an object: `t1.copyTo(&t2);`

Comment: If you're trying to copy t1 into t2, then you want:
   Time t2(&t1);

Comment: Tim Brauer! I received error by this way. Mr. leemes answered very nicely! I thank him

Comment: If you want to use `Time t2;` first, then copy it, write an assignment operator:
`Time& operator=(const Time& rhs) { //copy sutff}`

Comment: That's not why you got the error.  Your error was caused by incorrect syntax `Time(&t2);`

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor overload

```
     Time(Time *t){
         t->hour=this->hour;
         t->sec=this->sec;
     }
```

you probably misplaced `this` vs `t`, as you obviously want to copy the data from the passed object to the newly created one, instead of the other way around as you currently do.

Also, the member `min` is missing here.

```
     Time(Time *t){
         this->hour=t->hour;
         this->min=t->min;
         this->sec=t->sec;
     }
```

Then, to use this constructor, you need to give your new object a name. Change

```
Time(&t2);
```

into

```
Time t3(&t2);
```

This being said, you can simply copy class objects using assignment or copy construction. Appropriate copy constructor and assignment operator is created automatically for you. You can simply write `Time t3 = t2;` or `Time t3(t2);` and get rid of the above constructor.

Comment: I received correct answer in another way that It wasn't my mean. I don't want to define third object for copying attributes of two objects! What should I do?

Comment: I'm sorry. This comment was for another answer :(